# MongoDB and Mongoose - Recursive Propertie and Scheme

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var User = new Scheme({
   name: String,
   ...
   subscribers: [User]
});
```

Can I do this? If not - are there any other options?
And can I say `subscribers` property to have default value `[]` and type of `User`?

Comment: I just came across this - it absolutely can be recursive. [Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24964914/can-a-mongo-model-self-reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24964914/can-a-mongo-model-self-reference)