# How to do mongoose model self reference on Typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a model:

```js
const comment = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: { type: ObjectId, required: true },
  comment: { type: String },
  replies: [comment]
});
```

Want to create document like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "comment": "Grand Parent Comment",
  "replies": [
    {
      "id": 11,
      "comment": "Parent Comment",
      "replies": [
        {
          "id": 111,
          "comment": "Comment",
          "replies": [
            {
              "id": 1111,
              "comment": "Child Comment",
              "replies": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 112,
          "comment": "Sibling Comment",
          "replies": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

According to the answer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34679509/8271526)

> Can be solved just by using `this` as a reference to the model.

```js
  const comment = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: { type: ObjectId, required: true },
    comment: { type: String },
-   replies: [comment]
+   replies: [this]
  });
```

When i try with Typescript an error will appear like:

> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.

Any best practice to model self reference with mongoose writing on typescript.

Comment: the difference i see is that you're declaring with const and the example answer declared with var, perhaps?

Comment: sorry I think it makes no difference, because when I try to declare it with "var" or "const", the same error will still appear.

Answer (score 4):

You can try doing this in two steps instead with the `add` method:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  body: String,
});

schema.add({
 children: [schema]
});
```